# Kotlin - can i use an extension for method overloading?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have created a custom view in android. one of the methods has a signature like this:

```
fun show(CategoryFilterModel model) {/*...*/}
```

and it works fine. and now i'd like to create a overloaded function which would look like this if i did it by adding it to the custom view class:

```
fun show(ShopFilterModel model) {/*...*/}
```

Notice the type is different so this is a method overload.

a thought came to me that i could instead use an extension in kotlin to add another method to the class.

so it would like something like this:

```
fun MyCustomView.show(ShopFilterModel: model){

    }
```

is this advised or should i only add utility methods with extensions ? Are there any overheads ?

Comment: It will compile into a `static show(MyCustomView self, ShopFilterModel model)`. Runtime overheads, if any, will be very small.

Comment: sense it will compile into a static how can i reference object variables, i assume i cannot then, correct ?

Comment: It has the `self` argument, this is the instance holding the variables. But you can't access any `private` members and this could be a show-stopper.

Comment: There's a pitfall with extension funs and overloading: if the member's signature is compatible with your extension fun's, but more general, it will get selected before even considering yours.

Comment: very good point to know some of the drawbacks. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s not only for utilities, as you can read in this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35321347/8073652), which lists pretty much all use cases.

Imho, if you have control over that class you want to extend with a method, there’s no problem to add the method directly to it as opposed to doing it with an extension method. Yet, *technically you can consider doing this*. Please **be aware** that [calling such an extension function from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30880699/8073652) isn’t very idiomatic because it will be compiled to a `static` function. If it’s ever going to be invoked from Java, I’d rather use ordinary methods when possible.